# Local Wordpress env with Docker Compose - cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a local Wordpress environment using Docker Compose for the first time. I am currently able to access my Wordpress instance on `localhost:8080` and have the files mapped locally.

I purchased a theme, added it to `wp-content/themes`, and was then prompted to install some required plugins for it. When I click `Install`, this is the error I receive:

`Download failed. cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

Here is my configuration file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  my-wpdb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "8081:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  my-wp:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - my-wpdb:mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
```

Probably a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: `localhost` here is inside your container, so the port would be 80.

Comment: A possible solution is to keep 80 as port on localhost. This solves the issue, even if it does not allow individual configs

Answer (score 5):

Following on from papey's answer. curl is trying to connect on the outside port (8080 in your case) whilst inside the container (80).

After much Googling and the only solution people gave was changing the inside and outside ports to 80:80. This is not feasible if you are running another service on port 80.

My solution was to modify the Apache2 conf inside the container so that Apache will respond inside on the outside port. There may be better ways but this is working.

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with PaulH's solution.
Execute the following commands inside the running WordPress Linux Docker container then restart the container.

```
echo -e "\nListen 8080\n" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf
echo -e "\n<VirtualHost *:*>\n</VirtualHost>\n" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf && cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

According to you docker-compose :

```
  - "8080:80"
```

8080 is **OUTSIDE** the container

80 is **INSIDE** the container

Comment: How to connect to inside the container?

Comment: did you find a solution?